# if and when try/except statements are overkill

Tags: python-3.x

Sorry if this isn't the right place to ask this. I'm still learning a lot about good design. I was just wondering, say I process raw data through 20 functions. Is it idiotic or extremely slow to think of wrapping the contents of each function with a try/except statement, so if I ever run into issues I can see exactly where and why the data wasn't properly processed? Surely there's another more efficient way of facilitating the debugging process.

I've tried searching through articles for if and when to use try/except statements. But I think the experience of some of the guys on stack overflow will provide a much better answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I can only give my personal opinion, but i think you shouldn't wrap your entire code inside "try/except" conditions. To me, theses are meant for specific cases, when manipulating streams, sending HTTP request, to ensure that we don't reach a part of the code that won't run (or adopt specific behaviour depending on the error).
The risk is to catch an error from another line of your program, but without knowing it (for example if you wrap an entire function).

It is important to cover your code, but without completely hide every error that you could encounter.

you probably already checked it but a little reminders of good practices :

[Try / Except good practices](https://www.techbeamers.com/use-try-except-python/)

I hope that's will be helpful !

Answer (score 1):

When exceptions are raised (and recorded somewhere) they have a stacktrace showing the calls that lead to the error. That should be enough to trace where the problem was.

If you catch an exception at the lowest level, how will the subsequent  methods continue? They'll not get the returned values they were expecting. Better to let the exception propagate up the process to somewhere it makes sense to handle it. If you do manual checks you can raise specific exceptions with messages to help debug, eg:

```
def foo(bar):
    if bar < 0:
        raise ValueError(f"Can't foo a value less than 0, got {bar}")
    # foo bar here
```